# Isocam Not WORKING in blender 2.9

Tags: error

I tried everything to apply isocam add on in my blender 2.9 and I failed.

I used
https://github.com/jasonicarter/create-isocam
and I succeeded installing and applying it to my blender.
But whenever I try to do something with mesh.
It fails.

I captured the error message.
[image]

Does anyone know what i should do to fix it?
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Hello, the best way to troubleshoot issues from add-ons on github is to create a new issue to directly contact the developer : https://github.com/jasonicarter/create-isocam/issues

Comment: Does [this](https://github.com/jasonicarter/create-isocam/issues/4) apply here?